# Sitecore 8.2 website went down when MongoDB crashed, how to prevent

Tags: xdb, mongodb

Sitecore 8.2 Update 3
We have a single CM that also hosts MongoDB for analytics. We also have 2 CDs.

This morning MongoDB crashed when it apparently ran out of memory. I thought Sitecore was supposed to stay up even when MongoDB is unavailable but our website (only one site on our servers) went down.

Is there a config change I can make to Sitecore to prevent it from going down when/if MongoDB is unavailable?

Update:
Here's exerpts from the sitecore log:

> Exception: MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException
>   Message: Unable to connect to server ###.###.###.###:27017: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ###.###.###.###:27017.
>   Source: MongoDB.Driver
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.Connect(TimeSpan timeout, ReadPreference readPreference)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.ChooseServerInstance(ReadPreference readPreference)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.AcquireConnection(ReadPreference readPreference)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.RunCommandAs[TCommandResult](IMongoCommand command, ReadPreference readPreference, IBsonSerializer resultSerializer, IBsonSerializationOptions resultSerializationOptions)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.RunCommandAs[TCommandResult](IMongoCommand command, ReadPreference readPreference)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.FindAndModify(FindAndModifyArgs args)
>      at Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateStore.GetItemExclusive(String application, String id, SessionStateLockCookie lockCookie, Int32& flags)
>      at Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateProvider.GetItemExclusive(HttpContext context, String id, Boolean& locked, TimeSpan& lockAge, Object& lockId, SessionStateActions& actions)
>      at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.GetSessionStateItem()
>      at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>   Message: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ###.###.###.###:27017
>   Source: System
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEP)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.Open()
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(BsonBuffer buffer, Int32 requestId)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(MongoRequestMessage message)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.CommandOperation`1.Execute(MongoConnection connection)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.Ping(MongoConnection connection)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.Connect()
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.Connect(TimeSpan timeout, ReadPreference readPreference)

Here is an excerpt from the Mongo log:

> 2020-03-10T08:05:15.894-0400 I -        [conn24997] end connection 127.0.0.1:58181 (9 connections now open)
>   2020-03-10T08:05:15.895-0400 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58272 #25007 (9 connections now open)
>   2020-03-10T08:05:44.738-0400 I COMMAND  [conn25004] query Sitecore_analytics.Contacts query: { _id: BinData(3, B72E91A6722A0A4992582943D5D43BDB) } planSummary: IDHACK ntoskip:0 keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:20 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } },
>    Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } 1014ms
>   2020-03-10T08:06:00.898-0400 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:58277 #25008 (10 connections now open)
>   2020-03-10T08:06:00.899-0400 I -        [conn24999] end connection 127.0.0.1:58184 (10 connections now open)
>   2020-03-10T08:14:43.520-0400 I -        [conn25005] end connection ###.###.###.70:52362 (9 connections now open)
>   2020-03-10T08:17:11.280-0400 I -        [conn25001] end connection ###.###.50.62:60013 (8 connections now open)
>   2020-03-10T08:20:43.727-0400 I -        [conn25003] end connection ###.###.###.70:52354 (7 connections now open)
>   2020-03-10T08:21:22.597-0400 I -        [conn25000] end connection ###.###.###.70:52322 (6 connections now open)
>   2020-03-10T08:21:22.598-0400 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from ###.###.###.70:52405 #25009 (6 connections now open)
>   2020-03-10T08:26:42.901-0400 I CONTROL  [ftdc] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\stacktrace_windows.cpp(239)                                   mongo::printStackTrace+0x43
>   2020-03-10T08:26:42.901-0400 I CONTROL  [ftdc] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\signal_handlers_synchronous.cpp(332)                          mongo::reportOutOfMemoryErrorAndExit+0x90
>   2020-03-10T08:26:42.901-0400 I CONTROL  [ftdc] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\util\allocator.cpp(51)                                             mongo::mongoRealloc+0x19
>   2020-03-10T08:26:42.901-0400 I CONTROL  [ftdc] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\base\data_builder.h(179)                                           mongo::DataBuilder::resize+0x94
>   2020-03-10T08:26:42.901-0400 I CONTROL  [ftdc] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\ftdc\compressor.cpp(127)                                        mongo::FTDCCompressor::getCompressedSamples+0x14c
>   2020-03-10T08:26:42.901-0400 I CONTROL  [ftdc] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\ftdc\file_writer.cpp(168)                                       mongo::FTDCFileWriter::writeSample+0x135
>   2020-03-10T08:26:42.901-0400 I CONTROL  [ftdc] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\ftdc\file_manager.cpp(296)                                      mongo::FTDCFileManager::writeSampleAndRotateIfNeeded+0x48
>   2020-03-10T08:26:42.901-0400 I CONTROL  [ftdc] mongod.exe    ...\src\mongo\db\ftdc\controller.cpp(217)                                        mongo::FTDCController::doLoop+0x3f6
>   2020-03-10T08:26:42.901-0400 I CONTROL  [ftdc] mongod.exe    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(247)  std::_LaunchPad >,std::default_delete > > > >::_Run+0x75
>   2020-03-10T08:26:42.901-0400 I CONTROL  [ftdc] mongod.exe    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread(210)  std::_Pad::_Call_func+0x9
>   2020-03-10T08:26:42.901-0400 I CONTROL  [ftdc] ucrtbase.dll                                                                                   o__realloc_base+0x60
>   2020-03-10T08:26:42.901-0400 I CONTROL  [ftdc] KERNEL32.DLL                                                                                   BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
>   2020-03-10T08:26:42.901-0400 F -        [ftdc] out of memory.

Comment: here is the sitecore article for Sitecore XP behavior when MongoDB server is unavailable. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/930657.

Comment: That article doesn't address the reason why my site was completely unavailable. According to the site, the page will take longer to load, but mine never loaded. Based on the article, I would have expected the pages to load after 30 seconds (the timeout for xDB connection), but it never happened.

Comment: can you post your logs.

Comment: @Shrad I have added log data to my post.

Comment: sorry, i lost the track of this.
please comment out the below in connectionstring.config file  will keep your sitecore running. once you have resolved your memory issue revert it back. let me know is this something you are expecting.

<add name="analytics" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/analytics" />
  <add name="tracking.live" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_live" />
  <add name="tracking.history" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/tracking_history" />